# Retrieving values of all input fields within one table-row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, each

I have a table which `td`s are input fields and I need to retrieve all inserted values within one `tr`(representing one imported user). So html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Facebook ID</td>
       <?php foreach($newArray as $column){?>
       <?php echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';}?>
    </tr>
    <tr id="firstUser">
       <td><input type="text" name="facebook-id1" class="form-control klasa" placeholder=""></td>
       <?php foreach($newArray as $column){?>
       <?php echo '<td><input type="text" id="'.$column.'1" onfocus="findName(this)" name="'.$column.'1" class="form-control klasa"></td>';}?>
    </tr>

    <tr id="secondUser">
       <td><input type="text" name="facebook-id2" class="form-control klasa" placeholder=""></td>
       <?php foreach($newArray as $column){?>
       <?php echo '<td><input type="text" id="'.$column.'2" onfocus="findName(this)" name="'.$column.'2" class="form-control klasa"></td>';}?>
    </tr>
     <tr id="thirdUser">
       <td><input type="text" name="facebook-id3" class="form-control klasa" placeholder=""></td>
       <?php foreach($newArray as $column){?>
       <?php echo '<td><input type="text" id="'.$column.'3" onfocus="findName(this)" name="'.$column.'3" class="form-control klasa"></td>';}?>

    </tr>
    <tr id="fourthUser">
       <td><input type="text" name="facebook-id3" class="form-control klasa" placeholder=""></td>
       <?php foreach($newArray as $column){?>
       <?php echo '<td><input type="text" id="'.$column.'4" onfocus="findName(this)" name="'.$column.'4" class="form-control klasa"></td>';}?>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tried like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#plavoDugme').click(function() {
        var oneUser = {};
        $("#firstUser input").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            oneUser.first = $this.val();
        })

        $("#secondUser input").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            oneUser.second = $this.val();
        })

        $("#thirdUser input").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            oneUser.third = $this.val();
        })

        $("#fourthUser input").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            oneUser.fourth = $this.val();
        })
        console.log(oneUser);
    });
});
```

As you can see I tried to select all input fields within one `tr` like so: `$("#firstUser input")`, but when I `console.log(oneUser)` it displays only value of last input field within each table-row. Please help this is simple task but I'm stuck.

Comment: you should use an array and push the values into it

Comment: Give the name attribute same to the text box within one tr... then in jquery you can access using that name .. it will be array of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the below solution.

```
var userList = {};
$('#plavoDugme').click(function(){
    $('.dynamicList').find('tr').not(':first').each(function(){//loop all rows
       var $this = $(this);
       var userType = $this[0].id.replace('User', '');//get id without User text
       userList[userType] = [];//assign array to it
       $this.find('input').each(function(){//loop all input in single row
          userList[userType].push(this.value);//push input value in it
       });
    });
    console.log(userList);
});
```

Demo Link: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wdggjevg/)

Output of object:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly to my needs, adapting my code with a couple of classes to match your filter logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) function like following.

```
$('#plavoDugme').click(function () {
    var oneUser = {};
    oneUser.first = $("#firstUser input").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    });

    oneUser.second = $("#secondUser input").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    });
    oneUser.third = $("#thirdUser input").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    });
    oneUser.third = $("#fourthUser input").each(function () {
        return this.value;
    });

    console.log(oneUser);
});
```